# "Uncaught ReferenceError: createStoryJS is not defined" Error with Timeline JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline.js

I built out a demo page using Timeline JS and it works fine within a regular HTML file ([See Example Here](http://transitchurch.com/2015/our-story.html)). However, now that I am using it with ExpressionEngine platform (v 2.9.2), I get a javascript error and the area where the timeline should appear is blank ([See Here](https://transitchurch.com/ee2015/our-story)).

The js error message is "Uncaught ReferenceError: createStoryJS is not defined."  I'm not well versed with javascript so I do not know what that means or how to correct it. Please help.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this question keeps getting voted down? Did I use the wrong category or something?

Answer (score 1):

Per RainerJ on Experts-Exchange, I just needed to add the following reference.  It works like a charm now